# Getting Red X on datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am making Dashboard App and there about 10 dynamic gridview and chart on the Dashboard. Sometimes getting data from the database takes 2-3 seconds sometimes 10-15 seconds. So that's why i need to use multithreading all of on my views and charts. If i not use multithreading application freezes a lot.

However when i use multi-threading sometimes i get red X on my datagrid like below;

[Red Cross on Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSBAf.png)

I use all multithreads like below. If you have better usage for this, you can share also that too.

```
try
 {
   Task.Factory.StartNew(() => getCurrentActivity());
 }
 catch
  {
    // Do Nothing.
  }

public void getCurrentActivity()
{
    pct = 0;
    dtTopSQL.Clear();
    odaTopSQL = new OracleDataAdapter(getTopSQLDetails, oradb);
    odaTopSQL.Fill(dtTopSQL);

    dtCurTopSQL.Merge(dtTopSQL);

    if (uceTopSQL.SelectedIndex != 5)
    {
        maxDate = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable().Max(z => z.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME"));
        minDate = maxDate.AddSeconds(lastxminutes);
    }

    else if (uceTopSQL.SelectedIndex == 5)
    {
        maxDate = udteMax.DateTime;
        minDate = udteMin.DateTime;
    }

    var dt1 = dtCurTopSQL.AsEnumerable()
          .Where(l => l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") >= minDate && l.Field<DateTime>("SAMPLE_TIME") <= maxDate)
          .GroupBy(h => h.Field<string>("SQL_ID"))
          .Select(g =>
          {
              DataRow row2 = dtCurTopSQL.NewRow();
              row2["SQL_ID"] = g.Key;
              row2["CountAll"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("CountAll"));
              row2["CPU"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("CPU"));
              row2["Scheduler"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Scheduler"));
              row2["User I/O"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("User I/O"));
              row2["System I/O"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("System I/O"));
              row2["Concurrency"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Concurrency"));
              row2["Application"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Application"));
              row2["Commit"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Commit"));
              row2["Configuration"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Configuration"));
              row2["Administrative"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Administrative"));
              row2["Network"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Network"));
              row2["Queueing"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Queueing"));
              row2["Cluster"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Cluster"));
              row2["Others"] = g.Sum(h => h.Field<int>("Others"));
              row2["Activity"] = 0;
              return row2;
          }).CopyToDataTable();

    for (int ac = 0; ac < dt1.Rows.Count; ac++)
    {
        pct += Convert.ToInt32(dt1.Rows[ac][2]);
    }

    for (int abc = 0; abc < dt1.Rows.Count; abc++)
    {
        dt1.Rows[abc][3] = Convert.ToDouble(((double)100 / (double)pct).ToString()) * int.Parse(dt1.Rows[abc][2].ToString());
    }

    ugTopSQL.DataSource = dt1;

    ugTopSQL.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[3].CellAppearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Center;
    ugTopSQL.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[3].SortIndicator = SortIndicator.Descending;
    ugTopSQL.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[1].Header.Caption = "SQL ID";
    ugTopSQL.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].Hidden = true;
    ugTopSQL.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[2].Hidden = true;

}
```

Here is the errors after getting red Cross;

```
System.NullReferenceException: Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawChildElements(UIElementDrawParams& drawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawElement(UIElementDrawParams& defaultDrawParams)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UIElement.DrawHelper(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Boolean clipText, Boolean forceDrawAsFocused, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics, Nullable`1 zoomFactor)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode, Size elementSize, Boolean preventAlphaBlendGraphics)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.ControlUIElementBase.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridUIElement.Draw(Graphics graphics, Rectangle invalidRectangle, Boolean doubleBuffer, AlphaBlendMode alphaBlendMode)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   konum: Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   konum: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! - Also `try/catch` should be reserved for actual errors, not for control flow.. - Also: do try to translate the error message for us!! - Finally: Are the DGVs and Chart DataBound?? You give a little too little code..

Comment: Edited Question.

Comment: So you are using some Infragistics controls? Do add this to the tag and/or question!! And they are databound. Do learn all about how to trigger updates from a non-ui thread; I guess the redcross comes from trying to update while the datasource is locked.